# YII2 Form with GridView and Pjax

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, pjax

I have a view with to models: contact and phones, and I want to create a view to update this two models, my view is like this:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'Contact']); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput() ?>
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
<?= \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
    'id' => 'phonesGrid',
    'dataProvider' =>  new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $fones,
        'sort' => [
            'attributes' => ['number', 'ramal'],
        ],
        'pagination' => false,
    ]),
    'columns' => [
        'number',
        'ramal',
         ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn']
    ],
]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

The problem is when i call `$.pjax.reload` the action (create ou update) of `ContactController` is call but the request not has the form data of contact and the data entering is clear.
How can i do this in YII2?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. So your problem is that when you cann $.pjax.reload the Contact[name] field is emptied? If that is the case then you are probably refreshing the page and not using pjax.

Comment: see this article http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/772/pjax-on-activeform-and-gridview-yii2/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you get an empty response from the `pjax` call. This might be caused by the fact that you have your actual `form`(and it's `models`) are **outside** of the `pjax` call, causing it **NOT** to refresh them and making no ***connection*** whatsoever.

In my opionion it's best to contain ALL the data you have inside a `pjax` with `queries`/`models`. For instance:

```
<div class='resp-col col-12'>
    <?php Pjax::begin([
        'id'=>'all-tags',
        'timeout' => 5000,
    ]); ?>
<?php
$query = Tag::find();
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 20,
    ],
]);
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns'=> [
      'view'=>[
        'header'=>'view',
        'options'=>[
          'width'=>'5%'
        ],
        'format'=>'raw',
        'value'=>function ($data) {
            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>', Url::to(['detail', 'id'=>$data->id]), ['data-type'=>'modal', 'data-title'=>'View item']).
            '<a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" onclick=DeleteTag("'.$data->id.'")></span></a>';;
        },
      ],
      'name',
      'content',
    ]
]);
 ?>
<?php Pjax::end()?>
```

When a pjax.reload is called on all-tags, it will also perform a new query and therefore return a new array of data.

Hopefully this is helpful to you.